# How to sort data in chart by 3rd variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data.frame like this

```
head(df)
# Country Value1 Value2 Part
# Germany 2.5    3.5    West
# France  4.2    4.4    West
# Romania 10.3   5      East
# Latvia  12.2   13     East
```

I have chart like this

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=Country, xend=Country, y=Value1, yend=Value2), color="grey") +
  geom_point(aes(x=Country, y=Value1), color="red", size=3 ) +
  geom_point(aes(x=Country, y=Value2), color="blue", size=3 ) +
  theme_classic()
```

I want to sort data on x-axis by variable "Part".

Cheers guys.

---

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Country = structure(c(3L, 4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Romania", 
"Latvia", "Germany", "France"), class = "factor"), Value1 = c(2.5, 
4.2, 10.3, 12.2), Value2 = c(3.5, 4.4, 5, 13), Part = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("East", "West"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor"))), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Maybe `facet_wrap(~ Part, scales = "free_x")`?

Answer (score 1):

The plot from your example data looks like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=Country, xend=Country, y=Value1, yend=Value2), color="grey") +
  geom_point(aes(x=Country, y=Value1), color="red", size=3 ) +
  geom_point(aes(x=Country, y=Value2), color="blue", size=3 ) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

If you want to reorder the countries according to their `Part` column, first ensure you define the "correct" order of the `Part` column (however you would like this to be):

```r
df$Part <- factor(df$Part, levels = c("East", "West"))
```

Now order your countries' factors according to the order of the levels in `Part`:

```
df$Country <- factor(df$Country, levels = unique(df$Country[order(df$Part)]))
```

Your plot now looks like this:

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=Country, xend=Country, y=Value1, yend=Value2), color="grey") +
  geom_point(aes(x=Country, y=Value1), color="red", size=3 ) +
  geom_point(aes(x=Country, y=Value2), color="blue", size=3 ) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: If instead of ordering by `df$Part` you order by `f` defined as `f <- with(df, interaction(Part, Country));f <- factor(as.character(f))`, the countries will also be ordered within `Part`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas yes, I thought that was what the OP wanted?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. I'm saying this because in the graph Romania comes before Latvia and Germany before France. With `levels = unique(df$Country[order(f)])` they are in the right order.